# Why Django serialize returns string

Tags: python, django

I have problem with returning something browsable form `serializers.serialize`.

My model:

```
class BowlingGame(models.Model):
    Frame = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    FrameRow = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    Result = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    StrikeSpare = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    StrikeSpareInfo = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    Time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    GameId = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    StateOfGame = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('GameId',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.GameId)
```

And what I do next:

```
>>> from django.core import serializers
>>> from django.db.models import Max
>>> from game.models import BowlingGame
>>> a = BowlingGame.objects.all().aggregate(Max('GameId'))['GameId__max']
>>> game_frame = BowlingGame.objects.filter(GameId=a)
>>> me = serializers.serialize('json', game_frame, fields=('Frame', 'FrameRow'))
>>> me
'[{"model": "game.bowlinggame", "pk": 2356, "fields": {"Frame": 1, "FrameRow": 1}}, {"model": "game.bowlinggame", "pk": 2357,......}}]'
```

This seems to be string as

```
>>> me[0]
'['
```

and I'm looking for the first element of the queryset.

I tried few more things:

```
>>> me = serializers.serialize('json', [game_frame, ], fields=('Frame', 'FrameRow'))

AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

My question: is it normal to return string? How I can browse the object. In fact I'm using it with AJAX but its the same. `json.game_frame[0]` returns `'['`. I need to be able to get the elements separately as normal dict or list. What is going on?

Comment: But returning a string is what serialisation **is**. If you just want a queryset, why pass it to a serialiser at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meen. Sring and json are different things. I'm doing ajax call. I suggest you didn't get the question right.

Comment: You have a strange misunderstanding somewhere. JSON is a string serialisation format.

Comment: You are right, but it's not what I need. I was thinking that JsonResponse will allways return JSON. For example return JsonResponse({'game_frame': game_frame}) is going to give me JSON at my ajax so I can browse it. Any suggestion how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I just find a solution.
In my javascript file `var content = JSON.parse(json.game_frame)`.
It creates nice browseble objects.

Comment: `var` is javascript not python, use `json.loads()`